# Regex to match X digits or letters but not X letters in a row

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, regex-negation

I want to extract 7-char matches. Each character can be a digit or uppercase letter but the whole match can't be only uppercase letters. Example: let's say I have a test string like so:

`I want this nr A7A3G1A but not this ANTENNA`

So I should get `A7A3G1A` but not `ANTENNA`. A regex to match both would be: `[A-Z0-9]{7}`. Is it possible to somehow not allow only uppercase letters and still extract the 1st match?

Comment: Could it be only digits like `1234567`?

Comment: @Toto no, there have to be also letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
\b(?![A-Z]{7})[A-Z0-9]{7}\b
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N3bUtD/1)**

Here, word boundaries `\b` ensure only whole word is matched and `(?![A-Z]{7})` negative look ahead ensures what is matched is not all upper case letters and `[A-Z0-9]{7}` captures a word exactly of seven characters containing mix of upper case letters and digits.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use a positive lookahead `(?=` and then make sure to match at least 1 digit.

Use word boundaries `\b` to prevent the  match being part of a larger word.

```
\b(?=[A-Z0-9]{7}\b)[A-Z0-9]+[0-9][A-Z0-9]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vUDKZW/1)